# Dressing my dog causes her to attack my other dog

Tags: dogs, psychology, multi-pet-families

I own two small dogs. One is a pug, female, 3 years old. The other is a pomeranian, male, 6 years old.

If I put a shirt, or take a shirt off(and this includes harnesses) on the pug while the pom is around, she becomes agitated and starts to growl. Occasionally, maybe three out of the five times she is dressed, she will lunge at him and violently attack biting at his face. We've learned just not to dress/undress her around him.

I'm curious to know why this is happening? She tends to be a little shy around other animals, but she is always fine with my pom.

Comment: How does she respond to the dress and harness when the Pomeranian isn't around?

Comment: She still growls but generally OK with it we think.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess, but I think your pug doesn't like the harness and clothes - as you say, she still growls when getting the harness or clothes when the Pomeranian isn't around.
She doesn't want or dare to go against her masters, so she takes it out on the Pomeranian instead.
Since she's doing this when dressed and when undressed, it seems to be the event of being clothed/unclothed that she dislikes.